# Link an external url to the Title in Colorbox

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, colorbox

I am trying to add an external link to the Title in the images in colorbox, so that by clicking the title leads to an external page. Have added custom field in the posts( I am using Wordpress) and given key = 'url' and value = an external link, say http://facebook.com. Have around 10 images on my page.

I am calling the following in the jQuery ready function in my home.php, which further calls a loop.php to display the images in hp-thumb format. .

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
     jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
         var keyValues = new Array();
          keyValues = <?php echo get_post_custom_values('url');?>
          var newLandingPage =  keyValues[0];
          $("a[rel='colorbox']").colorbox({title:function() {
                return '<a href="' + newLandingPage + '" target="_blank">Go For This</a>';
        }
     });
  </script>
```

The problem is this is not displaying the Title at all. Where am I going wrong?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You may have to use a onComplete:function(){) and replace the title.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution. It was a small syntax mistake in php.
I needed to use:
var newLandingPage =  keyValues['0'];

And I am done.